# How to yield inside Array.some

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Hi i have a generator function which return a function like this,

```
*getClassifier(classifier) {
    if (!classifier) {
        return async(function *() {
            return true;
        });
    }

    if (classifier !== null && typeof classifier === "object") {
        return false;
    }

    let name = classifier.name;
    if (!this._classRegistry[name])
        throw new Error("Classifier " + name + " is not registered");
    let com = yield this.injector.resolve(this._classRegistry[name]);

    return (message) => com.classify(message, classifier.options);
}
```

and i make a unit test for this function, which looks like this

```
result = yield someclass.getClassifiers(classifier)(message);
```

but then i got confused on how to expect result using chai
example `expect(result).to.be.true;`

any hint or solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about what you are trying to accomplish here, however you can give a try to the [chai-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-generator) module, that allows you to do something like (from the docs):

```
expect(generator).to.yield(true);
```

Btw I think you're using yield the wrong way, yield is used from within a generator function to produce values. From the outside, you have to use an iterator to go through all the values produced by the generator function.

The use you make of the yield keyword in the second block of code makes no sense to me. Moreover I don't get why you are returning values from the generator. `yield *value*` is supposed to substitute `return *value*` in this situation.